# Are there default icons in PyQt/PySide?

Tags: python, user-interface, icons, pyqt, pyside

I'm reading a tutorial on PySide and I was thinking , do I need to find my own icons for every thing or is there some way to use some built in icons . That way I wouldn't need to find an entire new set of icons if I want my little gui to run on another desktop environment .

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What you need is Pyside QIcon.fromTheme function. 
Basicaly it creates QIcon object with needed icon from current system theme.

Usage:

`undoicon = QIcon.fromTheme("edit-undo")`

"edit undo" - name of the icon "type"/"function" can be found [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html)

This works on X11 systems, for MacOSX and Windows check QIcon documentation
[QIcon.fromTheme](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html?highlight=qicon#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme)

**Edit** Inserting this from the website, since last time it was a broken link.

> *static* PySide.QtGui.QIcon.**fromTheme**(*name[, fallback=QIcon()]*)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - **name** – unicode
> - **fallback** – [PySide.QtGui.QIcon](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html?highlight=qicon#PySide.QtGui.QIcon)
>
> **Return type:**
>
> [PySide.QtGui.QIcon](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html?highlight=qicon#PySide.QtGui.QIcon)
>
> Returns the [PySide.QtGui.QIcon](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html?highlight=qicon#PySide.QtGui.QIcon) corresponding to name in the current icon theme. If no such icon is found in the current theme
>   fallback is returned instead.
>
> The latest version of the freedesktop icon specification and naming specification can be obtained here:
>
> - http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html
> - http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html
>
> To fetch an icon from the current icon theme:
>
> ```
> undoicon = QIcon.fromTheme("edit-undo")
> ```
>
> Or if you want to provide a guaranteed fallback for platforms that do not support theme icons, you can use the second argument:
>
> ```
> undoicon = QIcon.fromTheme("edit-undo", QIcon(":/undo.png"))
> ```
>
> > **Note**
> >
> > By default, only X11 will support themed icons. In order to use themed icons on Mac and Windows, you will have to bundle a compliant theme in one of your [PySide.QtGui.QIcon.themeSearchPaths()](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html?highlight=qicon#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QIcon.themeSearchPaths) and set the appropriate [PySide.QtGui.QIcon.themeName()](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html?highlight=qicon#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QIcon.themeName) .
> >
> > **See also**
> >
> > - [PySide.QtGui.QIcon.themeName()](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html?highlight=qicon#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QIcon.themeName)
> > - [PySide.QtGui.QIcon.setThemeName()](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html?highlight=qicon#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QIcon.setThemeName)
> > - [PySide.QtGui.QIcon.themeSearchPaths()](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html?highlight=qicon#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QIcon.themeSearchPaths)

Comment: D'oh! I was so excited about finally finding a list of standard Qt icons, but the second link seems to be broken now. Any updates?

Comment: @MichaelScheper In case you didn't get a notice that I updated the answer, the answer has been updated with the new link along with the associated text.

Answer (score 14):

There is another way to access some of the standard builtin icons in PyQt/PySide using the standard pixmap in the default style. For example, the following creates an icon for opening a file:

```
self.style().standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_DialogOpenButton)
```

For the full list of standard pixmaps, see:

http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QStyle.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QStyle.StandardPixmap

Comment: `self` refers to `QtWidgets.QApplication` (in Qt5) or `QtGui.QApplication` (in Qt4) in case you want to use it where `self` is not one of the above.

Comment: It's a shame that these `SP_` icons are so limited. I wish they could add more to the list.

Answer (score 6):

In `PyQt5`, here's a simple example of creating a push button with the play icon:

```
play_button = QtGui.QPushButton('Play video')
play_button.setIcon(QtGui.QApplication.style().standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
```

The Qt5 documentation provides a list of the possible SP ("Standard Pixmap") icons. See `enum QStyle::StandardPixmap` here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html

Comment: `QtGui.QPushButton`, Seriously? that is PyQt4 not PyQt5.

Comment: I had luck with the following line to set icon: `play_button.setIcon(qApp.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))` where `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import qApp, QStyle`

Comment: this example is for ```PyQt4```, in ```PyQt5``` it should be ```QtWidgets.QApplication....QtWidgets,QStyle....```

Answer (score 3):

I keep having trouble finding images of the standard icons, so for future reference: http://nukesaq88.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/04/12/005525

And the code I'm using (PyQt4, Pyside probably similar):

```
    # In method of QMainWindow subclass
    stdicon = self.style().standardIcon
    style = QtGui.QStyle
    reload_foo = QtGui.QAction(stdicon(style.SP_BrowserReload), '&Reload', self)
```

It would be nice if the (obviously auto-generated) [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum) had pictures in the standardIcons enum table...

Answer (score 2):

Another PyQt5 example using the [standard icons](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum) ([eqzx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209246/eqzx)'s answer didn't work for me):

```
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QStyle
 from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

 desktop_icon = QIcon(QApplication.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DesktopIcon)
```

Answer (score 1):

A PyQt5 example that will display all built-in icons (the list is from the [QStyle docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum)).

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QStyle, QWidget)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        icons = [
            'SP_ArrowBack',
            'SP_ArrowDown',
            'SP_ArrowForward',
            'SP_ArrowLeft',
            'SP_ArrowRight',
            'SP_ArrowUp',
            'SP_BrowserReload',
            'SP_BrowserStop',
            'SP_CommandLink',
            'SP_ComputerIcon',
            'SP_DesktopIcon',
            'SP_DialogAbortButton',
            'SP_DialogApplyButton',
            'SP_DialogCancelButton',
            'SP_DialogCloseButton',
            'SP_DialogDiscardButton',
            'SP_DialogHelpButton',
            'SP_DialogIgnoreButton',
            'SP_DialogNoButton',
            'SP_DialogNoToAllButton',
            'SP_DialogOkButton',
            'SP_DialogOpenButton',
            'SP_DialogResetButton',
            'SP_DialogRetryButton',
            'SP_DialogSaveAllButton',
            'SP_DialogSaveButton',
            'SP_DialogYesButton',
            'SP_DialogYesToAllButton',
            'SP_DirClosedIcon',
            'SP_DirHomeIcon',
            'SP_DirIcon',
            'SP_DirLinkIcon',
            'SP_DirLinkOpenIcon',
            'SP_DirOpenIcon',
            'SP_DockWidgetCloseButton',
            'SP_DriveCDIcon',
            'SP_DriveDVDIcon',
            'SP_DriveFDIcon',
            'SP_DriveHDIcon',
            'SP_DriveNetIcon',
            'SP_FileDialogBack',
            'SP_FileDialogContentsView',
            'SP_FileDialogDetailedView',
            'SP_FileDialogEnd',
            'SP_FileDialogInfoView',
            'SP_FileDialogListView',
            'SP_FileDialogNewFolder',
            'SP_FileDialogStart',
            'SP_FileDialogToParent',
            'SP_FileIcon',
            'SP_FileLinkIcon',
            'SP_LineEditClearButton',
            'SP_MediaPause',
            'SP_MediaPlay',
            'SP_MediaSeekBackward',
            'SP_MediaSeekForward',
            'SP_MediaSkipBackward',
            'SP_MediaSkipForward',
            'SP_MediaStop',
            'SP_MediaVolume',
            'SP_MediaVolumeMuted',
            'SP_MessageBoxCritical',
            'SP_MessageBoxInformation',
            'SP_MessageBoxQuestion',
            'SP_MessageBoxWarning',
            'SP_RestoreDefaultsButton',
            'SP_TitleBarCloseButton',
            'SP_TitleBarContextHelpButton',
            'SP_TitleBarMaxButton',
            'SP_TitleBarMenuButton',
            'SP_TitleBarMinButton',
            'SP_TitleBarNormalButton',
            'SP_TitleBarShadeButton',
            'SP_TitleBarUnshadeButton',
            'SP_ToolBarHorizontalExtensionButton',
            'SP_ToolBarVerticalExtensionButton',
            'SP_TrashIcon',
            'SP_VistaShield',
        ]

        layout = QGridLayout()

        for n, name in enumerate(icons):
            btn = QPushButton(name)
            pixmapi = getattr(QStyle.StandardPixmap, name)
            icon = self.style().standardIcon(pixmapi)
            btn.setIcon(icon)
            layout.addWidget(btn, int(n / 4), n % 4)

        self.setLayout(layout)

app = QApplication([])
w = Window()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Works fine in PyQt6 by changing PyQt5 to PyQt6.

Answer (score 0):

in PyQt, the window icon is by default the Qt logo. I think you will have to find your own icons for things inside the gui.