# How do I add StandardPixmap to a layout?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qpixmap

I am trying to get the built in [StandardPixmaps](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QStyle.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QStyle.StandardPixmap)
to display on my layout.

So far I have managed to access a standard pixmap (`PyQt4.QtGui.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxWarning`), but seem unable to actually add this to my layout.  I have tried adding it to a QLabel using the setPixmap method, but this requires a pixmap, not a standardPixmap.

I have found [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24151141/3725279), which led me to the standardPixmaps, but I have been unable to make any more progress from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PyQt4.QtGui.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxWarning` is an enumeration value not a pixmap.

In order to get a pixmap from it, you could give it to the [`standardPixmap`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle-obsolete.html#standardPixmap) method of the current used style.

Example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    label = QtGui.QLabel()
    label.setPixmap(app.style().standardPixmap(QtGui.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxWarning))
    label.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Unfortunately, the `standardPixmap` method is considered obsolete now. The Qt doc advises to use the [`standardIcon`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle.html#standardIcon) method which returns a [`QIcon`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qicon.html).

If you still want to use a `QLabel` to display your icon, you have to build a `QPixmap` from the `QIcon` you get. You can use one of its [`pixmap`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qicon.html#pixmap) methods for this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    label = QtGui.QLabel()
    icon =  app.style().standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxWarning)
    label.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(32))
    label.show()
    app.exec_()
```